# Urban AirShip Rich Push Notification inbox Orientation Change

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, urbanairship.com

Hello i am using Urban AirShip Rich Push Notification for IOS in cocos2d. I am getting the inbox for the Rich Notification but i am getting it in potrait mode. I want to get the inbox in the landscape mode.

Here is the code i am using

```
  [UAInbox useCustomUI:[UAInboxUI class]];//sample UI implementation
    [UAInbox shared].pushHandler.delegate = [UAInboxUI shared];

   // If the application gets an UAInbox message id on launch open it up immediately.
    // Only works for the default inbox
    [UAInboxUI shared].inboxParentController=window_.rootViewController;
    [UAInboxPushHandler handleLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

     if ([[UAInbox shared].pushHandler hasLaunchMessage]) {
        [[[UAInbox shared] uiClass] loadLaunchMessage];
    }

    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [UAInbox displayInbox:window_.rootViewController animated:YES];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Solved this problem by myself. Urban Airship already has build up capability to show in landscape mode.

Always write methods to display UAInbox in the AppDelegate.mm(in my case i needed to show the inbox in the boot up) in the viewdidfinishwithlaunchingoptions

Also if you want to add UrbanAirship inbox on button click(from a cocos2d scene) then for it to display properly always add it to the rootViewController of your cocos2d game in my case in `window_.rootViewController` instead of showing UrbanAirship in the scene by adding it to uiviewcontroller and showing the uiviewcontroller to the cocos2d scene using `the [[CCDirector SharedDirector]view]addsubview:uiviewcontroller].`

Comment: if the rich inbox message has button with action how to handle?